# Google sheet app script - Copy data from one sheet to another based on condition with loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to the forum and new to Google App Script.
I have a sheet with multiple tabs.
I want to do is probably very simple, but seems quite complex to me, coming from VBA...

I would like to: IF Facture(lastrow, 5) = 1 THEN copy-paste DetailDevis(i,1) to DetailFacture(lastrow,3) every time DetailDevis(i,2) = Facture(lastrow,2)

I have made the following, and i would love to get feed back as of why it does not work...

```
    function onEdit()
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
 var Facture = ss.getSheetByName("FactureDevis") ;
 var FactureDetail = ss.getSheetByName("DetailFactureDevis") ;
 var DevisDetail = ss.getSheetByName("DetailDevis") ;
 var FactureLR = Facture.getLastrow() ;
 var Situ1R = Facture.getRange(FactureLR,5) ;
 var Situ1V = Situ1R.getValues() ;
 var FactureDevisR = Facture.getRange(FactureLR,2) ;
 var FactureDevisV = FactureDevisR.getValues() ;
 var DevisDetailLR = DevisDetail.getLastrow() ;
 var FactureDetailLR = FactureDetail.getLastrow() ;
if (Situ1V == 1)
{
    for (var i = 2 ; i <= DevisDetalLR ; i++) {
 if (DevisDetail.getRange(i,2).getValue() == FactureDevisV)
 {
DevisDetail.getRange(i,1).copyTo(FactureDetail.getRange(FactureDetailLR,3);
}}}
```

Here are some additional questions:

- Is getLastrow() dynamic?
- Is the place you set your var crucial? Or can you set them all at the beginning?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. `Situ1V == 1` always will return `false` because `Situ1R.getValues()` return an Array of Arrays (also called multidimensional Array and  2D Array). It's not clear why you are naming your function onEdit. Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets, https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting. If you need further help, please clarify how is function being called add some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Thanks Rubén. I named the function onEdit because it will be triggered when a new row is added. I will read what i have sent as i could not understand anything regarding array of arrays...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh1 = e.source.getSheetByName("FactureDevis");
  var sh2 = e.source.getSheetByName("DetailFactureDevis");
  var sh3 = e.source.getSheetByName("DetailDevis");
  var sh1lr = sh1.getLastrow();
  var Situ1V = sh1.getRange(sh1lr, 5).getValue();
  var FactureDevisV = sh1.getRange(sh1lr, 2).getValue();
  var sh3lr = sh3.getLastrow();
  var sh2lr = sh2.getLastrow();
  if (Situ1V == 1) {
    for (var i = 2; i <= sh3lr; i++) {
      if (sh3.getRange(i, 2).getValue() == FactureDevisV) {
        sh3.getRange(i, 1).copyTo(sh2.getRange(sh2lr, 3));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

sheet.getLastRow() is a function so each time you call it, it recalculates the value.
I create my variables before I need them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tweaked it a bit, so that i do not get any more error. However, what it does is copy paste the occurrence of sh3 to the last row of sh2. I added +1 to sh2lr but it does not change the issue. Also, what is the e used for? I took it off as i could not get rid of the errors with it.

Comment: The e is the event object which is supplied by the onEdit trigger.  You can't run this type of function without provided the event object it is best to debug while it's runninng using e.source.toast(), Logger.log or console.log

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the whole idea.
Instead of copying each row in one sheet and pasting int into another sheet, i have gone for a filtering option:

```
function create_filter(){
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const s1 = ss.getSheetByName("DetailDevis");
    const s2 = ss.getSheetByName("FactureDevis");
    const s3 = ss.getSheetByName("DetailFactureDevis");
    const s3lr = s3.getLastRow();
    const range = s1.getRange("B:B");
    const datatocheck = s2.getRange(s2.getLastRow(),2).getValue();
    const filter = range.createFilter();
    const Filter_Criteria1 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextContains(datatocheck);
    const coll1 = 2;
    
    const add_filter1 =  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(coll1,Filter_Criteria1);

  const range2 = s1.getRange("A2:A");


  range2.copyTo(s3.getRange(s3lr,3));

filter.remove();
}
```

A new question has arisen now.
How can I trigger this function if a row is added to the FactureDevis sheet?

Thanks

Comment: Follow up questions should be posted as a new question, not in an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).